# returns a list of prime numbers from the argument list, all numbers in the result list should be unique

Tags: c#, list, duplicates, primes

My task is:
Please, implement the GetListOfPrimeNumbers method that returns a list of prime numbers from the argument list.
All numbers in the result list should be unique, duplicates should not be added to the result list.
The number is prime if its only dividers are 1 and this number itself.
using Linq is forbidden

Given numbers:
{23}{27}{29}{5}{30}{8}{19}{29}{26}{8}{17}{24}{19}{4}{4}{9}{15}{6}{9}{29}

Expected:      {23}{29}{5}{19}{17}

Actual:        {23}{27}{29}{5}{19}{29}{17}{19}{9}{15}{9}{29}

I've written this code:

```
        List<int> numbers2 = new List<int>();
        foreach (int x in numbers)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
            {
                if (x % i == 0)

                {

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    numbers2.Add(x);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
       
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers2[i] == numbers2[i + 1])
            {
                numbers2.Remove(numbers2[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers2[i] == numbers2[i + 1])
            {
                numbers2.Remove(numbers2[i]);
            }
        }
        return numbers2;
```

what is the mistake? help, please!

Comment: Store them in a hashset, not a list. Also investigate why your code thinks `27` and `15` are primes, when they clearly aren't.

Comment: You don't check if number is already present in the list, so you add same number many times.

Comment: thanks, i've checked if numbers is already present in the list.
This helps avoid duplicates

Comment: But i still have 27 and 15((

Comment: Hint - `numbers2.Add(x);` should be _outside_ of the loop, not in the else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try that :)

```
int[] nums = { 23, 27, 29, 5, 30, 8, 19, 29, 26, 8, 17, 24, 19, 4, 4, 9, 15, 6, 9, 29 };
        List<int> numbers = nums.ToList();
        List<int> numbers2 = new List<int>();
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            bool IsprimeNumber = true;
            long value = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(number));
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                IsprimeNumber = false;
            }
            for (long i = 3; i <= value; i = i + 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    IsprimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (IsprimeNumber)
            {
                if (!numbers2.Contains(number))
                {
                    numbers2.Add(number);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (int numero in numbers2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numero);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```